# Plot the ranges of values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am interested in plotting the range of values of variables so that the names appear on the Y-axis and the range on the X-axis, for a better visualization.

I have used the following code:

```
primer_matrix1a <- matrix(
  c(
    "EF1", 65, 217,
    "EF6",  165, 197,
    "EF14", 96, 138,
    "EF15", 103, 159,
    "EF20", 86, 118,
    "G9", 115, 173,
    "G25", 112, 140,
    "BE22", 131, 135,
    "TT20", 180, 190
  )
  ,nrow=9,ncol=3,byrow = T)

# Format data
Primer_name <- primer_matrix1a[,1]
Primer_name <- matrix(c(Primer_name),nrow = 9,byrow = T)
Primer_values<- matrix(c(as.numeric(primer_matrix1a[ ,2-3])),nrow = 9,ncol = 2,byrow = T)
Primer_Frame <- data.frame(Primer_name,Primer_values)
colnames(Primer_Frame) <- c("Primer","min","max")
Primer_Frame$mean<- mean(c(Primer_Frame$min,Primer_Frame$max))


ggplot(Primer_Frame, aes(x=Primer))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype=2,color="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(y=min),size=3,color="red")+
  geom_point(aes(y=max),size=3,color="red")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

but the plot is weird, EF15 goes from 103, 159, while G9 goes from 115 to 173, and they do not overlap, so I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like something is getting muddled when you are joining the matrix, but the approach is already more complex than it should be, so you might want to start afresh. It is probably easiest converting it to a dataframe and then formatting it there, rather than fiddling around with all the matrix functions:

```
df <- as.data.frame(primer_matrix1a)
names(df)<- c("Primer","min","max")
df$min <- as.numeric(as.character(df$min)) # Converts factor to numeric
df$max <- as.numeric(as.character(df$max))
df$mean<- mean(c(df$min,df$max))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Primer))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype=2,color="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(y=min),size=3,color="red")+
  geom_point(aes(y=max),size=3,color="red")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]