# Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`: ! geom_linerange requires the following missing aesthetics: x, ymin and ymax or y, xmin and xmax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
head(all)
basisOfProxy   method      citation        season    low   high       season.method.basis
beetle         CRACLE Fletcher et al 2019b  Tmin  -23.50 -20.40        Tmin_CRACLE_beetle
beetle      CRACLE-CA Fletcher et al 2019b  Tmin  -25.00 -10.40     Tmin_CRACLE-CA_beetle
plant          CRACLE  Fletcher et al 2017  Tmin  -12.18 -11.51         Tmin_CRACLE_plant
plant       CRACLE-CA  Fletcher et al 2017  Tmin  -21.70  -8.10      Tmin_CRACLE-CA_plant
plant          cRacle          Unpublished  Tmin  -13.48 -10.53         Tmin_cRacle_plant
plant  Unweighted MCR          Unpublished  Tmin  -28.50  -3.16 Tmin_Unweighted MCR_plant
```

```
str(all)
'data.frame':   39 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ basisOfProxy       : chr  "beetle" "beetle" "plant" "plant" ...
 $ method             : chr  "CRACLE" "CRACLE-CA" "CRACLE" "CRACLE-CA" ...
 $ citation           : chr  "Fletcher et al 2019b" "Fletcher et al 2019b" "Fletcher et al 2017" "Fletcher et al 2017" ...
 $ season             : chr  "Tmin" "Tmin" "Tmin" "Tmin" ...
 $ low                : num  -23.5 -25 -12.2 -21.7 -13.5 ...
 $ high               : num  -20.4 -10.4 -11.5 -8.1 -10.5 ...
 $ season.method.basis: chr [1:39, 1] "Tmin_CRACLE_beetle" "Tmin_CRACLE-CA_beetle" "Tmin_CRACLE_plant" "Tmin_CRACLE-CA_plant" ...
```

I am trying to make a plot using geom_linerange and ggplot to make a plot that is a box or thick line of the range (low to high) on the Y axis, with season.method.basis as the labels for each data point, something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203203/plot-the-ranges-of-values-in-r) in terms of the orientation and what I am communicating, but looking more like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285274/ggplot-ranges-of-values-as-discrete-linerange-plots) in terms ofjust having a solid bar representing the range.

I have tried a few different methods based on examples I have found here on stackexchange, for example:

```
Example 1
ggplot() +
  geom_linerange(data = all, aes(x = season.method.basis, ymin = low, 
                                 ymax = high, lwd = 1, color = season)) +
  scale_y_continuous(c(-30, 30))

#Example 2
ggplot(all) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x= season.method.basis, ymin=low, ymax=high, lwd=1, colour=season))

#eExample 3
ggplot(all, aes(x = season.method.basis)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=low,ymax=high), linetype=2,color="blue")
```

I also saw that in the example in ?ggplot x was a factor. Whether what looked like text was factors in other examples I could not tell, so I tried converting season.method.basis to factors and tried that.

```
all$fsmb <- factor(all$season.method.basis) 

Example 1
ggplot() +
  geom_linerange(data = all, aes(x = fsmb, ymin = low, 
                                 ymax = high, lwd = 1, color = season)) +
  scale_y_continuous(c(-30, 30))

#Example 2
ggplot(all) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x= fsmb, ymin=low, ymax=high, lwd=1, colour=season))

#eExample 3
ggplot(all, aes(x = fsmb)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=low,ymax=high), linetype=2,color="blue")
```

Every variant still results in the same error.

Seemingly similar examples include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733011/how-to-solve-geom-linerange-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-x-ymin) but they specified y=  xmin= and xmax=, which were then being ingnore with x, ymin, and ymax not specified, whereas I have (tried to?) specify x , ymin and ymax.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193104/using-geom-errorbar-in-ggplot2-results-in-error-geom-errorbar-requires-the-fol) is the same error, but I have them concatenated, so the solution doesn't seem to apply here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533315/how-to-solve-the-following-error-in-geom-errorbar-requires-the-following-missi) they did not specify the x at all, whereas I believe I have it in the same position as recommended in the answer in at least some of the examples.

I assume I have missed something simple, but I am stumped.

Comment: I tried running the code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203203/plot-the-ranges-of-values-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 
and did not get the plot they output - I just got the same error as per my subject line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears to be caused by a clash with other libraries. I do not know which library. To solve the error I unloaded all libraries, restarted R, and loaded only ggplot2.
On running the code I pointed to in the comment above, it now produced the same result as the OP of that question.
I tried rerunning the code I have above, and I now get (awful!) plots and no error.